# Are these two lottery tickets purchased back-to-back a little non-random?

Tags: random

I'm a student of languages, not math, so forgive the naivete of this question, please.

I bought two lottery tickets back-to-back from the same machine:

```
39 50 52 56 66 14  
08 39 51 63 66 02
```

Would two matching numbers `39,66` and the contiguous sequence `50-51-52` be the kind of thing that shouldn't occur if the generated numbers were being generated   "randomly"?   My intuition is that a certain degree of what might look like repeating patterns is to be expected in a random sequence, but this seems a little much.

Comment: How many numbers does this lottery allow ?

Comment: No, they are as random as any other set of numbers (think of them as different shapes (the numeric quantity of each element is absolutely meaningless here)).

Comment: first five numbers (1 to 75); final number (1 to 15); numbers cannot repeat; once used in a given "column" it is removed from the pool of possible numbers.

Comment: The human (and perhaps animal) brain is very good at "seeing" patterns  that are not necessarily there. It can be a useful survival device. One can conclude  little or nothing from such a small sample.

Comment: The probability that from the $5$ numbers, two or more coincide, is about $0.033$, so this event occurs in $1$ out of $30$ cases. Surprising, but not a reason to doubt the randomness. I have not calculated, how likely the other event is.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  Is the probability that a number will be immediately "adjacent"  double the probability that the numbers will coincide, since there are two adjacent possibilities?

Comment: ... excluding the upper and lower bounds, that is, 1 and 75, which have only one adjacent possibility?